# Removing curly brackets from a tuple in python

Tags: python, tkinter, tuples

I'm creating a test module to eventually import into a larger program using python.

My test module uses tkinter widgets to display a list of numbers that increases when a button is pressed.

```
import tkinter
import math

#Defining Variables

global Counter
Counter = 0
global ArrayDisplay1
ArrayDisplay1 = Counter


#Defining the GUI
class simpleapp_tk(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialise()

    def initialise(self):

        #Creating the GUI

        self.grid()
        self.resizable(False, False)

        self.labelVariableArray3 = tkinter.StringVar()
        ArrayLabel3 = tkinter.Label(self, textvariable=self.labelVariableArray3, anchor='w',bg='white')
        ArrayLabel3.grid(column=2, row=5, columnspan=5, sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariableArray3.set("")

        ArrayButton2 = tkinter.Button(self, text=u"Next Number", command=self.ArrayClick2)
        ArrayButton2.grid(column=2, row=3, sticky='EW')


    def ArrayClick2(self):
        global Counter
        global ArrayDisplay1
        Counter = Counter + 1
        if Counter == 1:
            ArrayDisplay1 = (Counter)
            self.labelVariableArray3.set(ArrayDisplay1)
        else:
            ArrayDisplay1 = (ArrayDisplay1, ",", Counter)
            self.labelVariableArray3.set(ArrayDisplay1)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('Arrays, Sorts and Searches')
    app.mainloop()
```

my problem lies within the 'ArrayClick2' module.
I wrote the code hoping to have the output be:

1

1, 2

1, 2, 3
and so on. However I instead get:

1

1, 2

{1, 2}, 3

{{1, 2}, 3}, 4
and so forth.
I tried using replace and strip, but neither of these seem to work with a tuple. Can someone tell me of another way to create this list or just to remove the brackets?

Also I've been told by the head of the program development that I can't use the python function named list because for some reason that I couldn't understand it was incompatible with the main program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate tuples using + for example `tuple0 = tuple0 + (element,)`.

To get your result from tuple you can use join

`''.join(str(element) + ',' for element in ArrayDisplay1)[:-1]`

[:-1] to ignore last element which is `,`

Without changing your code, Changes are:

line 9 : `ArrayDisplay1 = (Counter,)` ArrayDisplay1 must be a tuple

if else statement in ArrayClick2 function:

```
if Counter == 1:
        ArrayDisplay1 = (Counter,)
        self.labelVariableArray3.set(ArrayDisplay1)
else:
        ArrayDisplay1 +=(Counter,)
        self.labelVariableArray3.set(''.join(str(i)+',' for i in ArrayDisplay1)[:-1])
```

Comment: at what point do I actually implement this into the code? I'm not familiar with this function and I don't know how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was trying to make it so there was a space between the comma and the most recent number but that just caused another comma to be made in the wrong place. Is there a way to do this or do I just have to deal with it?

Comment: Never Mind I figured it out. Thanks again